# Match arrays efficiently, drop found keys in 2nd array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Essentially i have 2 arrays. 
the resulting `unmatched` array has duplicates, it should drop item in the array once found, which will lead to the `countB` variable being smaller once it is finished and no duplicates i the `unmatched` array

```js
const arr1 = ['Bill', 'Bob', 'John'];
const arr2 = ['Bill', 'Jane', 'John'];
const matched = [];
const unmatched = [];
countA = 0;
countB = 0;
/* Result expected
matched = [Bill, John]
unmatched = [Bob, Jane] */

arr1.forEach((e1) => {
countA++;
  for (const e2 of arr2) {
    countB++;
    if (e1 == e2) {
      matched.push(e1);
      break;
    } else {
      unmatched.push(e2);
     }
  }
});
console.log("unmatched",unmatched);
console.log("matched", matched);
console.log(`Counts  ForEach Loop A:${countA} For In Loop B:${countB}`);
```

The Result expected are two arrays:

```
    matched = [Bill, John]
```

```
    unmatched = [Bob, Jane]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and check if the actual value of the second array is in the set or not. Take the array as required and push the element to it.

```js
const
    array1 = ['Bill', 'Bob', 'John'],
    array2 = ['Bill', 'Jane', 'John'],
    set1 = new Set(array1),
    matched = [],
    unmatched = [];

array2.forEach(v => (set1.delete(v) ? matched : unmatched).push(v));
unmatched.push(...set1);

console.log(matched);
console.log(unmatched);
```

Comment: Bob got lost at sea?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Array.prototype.indexOf()` for that

```
for ( let i = 0; i = arr1.length; i++ ) {
    if ( arr2.indexOf( arr1[i] ) > -1 )
        matched.push( arr1[i] );
    else
        unmatched.push( arr[i] );
}
```

```js
const arr1 = ['Bill', 'Bob', 'John'];
const arr2 = ['Bill', 'Jane', 'John'];
const matched = [];
const unmatched = [];
countA = 0;
countB = 0;
/* Result expected
matched = [Bill, John]
unmatched = [Jane] */

for (let i = 0; (i < arr1.length); i++) {
    countA++;
  if (arr2.indexOf(arr1[i]) > -1) matched.push(arr1[i] );
  else unmatched.push(arr1[i]); countB++;
}
console.log('unmatched', unmatched);
console.log('matched', matched);
console.log(`Counts  ForEach Loop A:${countA} For In Loop B:${countB}`);
```

Comment: gives me an infinite loop.